# Ejecutar codigo una vez acabada una animación (Kotlin, Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Tengo un progressBar con una animacion, cual seria la forma correcta de poder ejecutar codigo justo despues de cuando termine la animacion?? (porque todo el codigo que ponga debajo se ejecuta a la vez que la animacion y no despues). Muchas gracias.

```
val animacion = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", progreso)
            .setDuration(10000)
            .start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más simple es crear un listener con el método `doOnEnd`

```
val animacion = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", progreso)
    .setDuration(10000)
animacion.start()
animacion.doOnEnd {
    // coloca el código aquí
}
```

También puedes ahorrarte la declaración de la variable usando una [scope function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html)

```
ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, "progress", progreso).run {  
    duration = 10_000
    doOnEnd { 
        // coloca el código aquí
    }
    start()
}
```